# Looking for a package regarding Schur Polynomials and Kostka numbers

Tags: polynomials, packages, combinatorics

I'm currently looking for any Mathematica package that involves Schur polynomials and/or Kostka numbers.

More generally, I'd be happy with anything that expands on symmetric polynomials in general.  Does such a thing exist?  I've had no luck finding any.

Answer (score 13):

I couldn't find a package, so here's my modest attempt at an implementation. I used only the standard identities, and I'm sure there are more efficient implementations (see e.g. [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-05-01780-1) for another algorithm for Schur functions, and see [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10801-006-0008-5) on the complexity of computing Kostka numbers).

So, having warned y'all of my implementations being a bit inefficient, here they are:

```
validPartitionQ[part_] :=
          VectorQ[part, (IntegerQ[#] && NonNegative[#]) &] && Apply[GreaterEqual, part]

SchurPolynomial[part_?validPartitionQ, vars_List] /; Length[part] <= Length[vars] :=
  Module[{n = Length[vars], tmp},
         tmp = C /@ Range[n];
         Cancel[Det[Outer[Power, tmp, PadLeft[Reverse[part], n] + Range[0, n - 1]]]/
                Det[LinearAlgebra`VandermondeMatrix[tmp]]] /. Thread[tmp :> vars]]

MonomialSymmetricPolynomial[part_?validPartitionQ, vars_List] /;
Length[part] <= Length[vars] :=
  Module[{n = Length[vars], tmp},
         tmp = C /@ Range[n];
         Sum[Inner[Power, tmp, perm, Times], {perm, Permutations[PadRight[part, n]]}] /.
         Thread[tmp :> vars]]

reverseLexicographicQ[p1_?validPartitionQ, p2_?validPartitionQ] /;
Total[p1] == Total[p2] := 
      p1 === p2 ||
      Catch[Scan[With[{tmp = Order @@ #}, If[tmp != 0, Throw[tmp == -1]]] &,
                 Flatten[{p1, p2}, {{2}, {1}}]]]

KostkaNumber[p1_, p1_] /; validPartitionQ[p1] := 1

KostkaNumber[{n_Integer}, p2_?validPartitionQ] /; Total[p2] == n := 1

KostkaNumber[p1_?validPartitionQ, p2_?validPartitionQ] /; 
   Total[p1] == Total[p2] && ! reverseLexicographicQ[p1, p2] := 0

KostkaNumber[p1_?validPartitionQ, p2_?validPartitionQ] /; Total[p1] == Total[p2] := 
 KostkaNumber[p1, p2] = Module[{n = Total[p1], m, pl, tmp},
   m = Max[Length[p1], Length[p2]]; tmp = C /@ Range[m]; pl = IntegerPartitions[n, m];
   Extract[First[
      PolynomialReduce[SchurPolynomial[p1, tmp], 
                       Table[MonomialSymmetricPolynomial[ip, tmp], {ip, pl}], tmp, 
                       CoefficientDomain -> Integers, MonomialOrder -> Lexicographic]],
           First[Position[pl, p2]]]]
```

Some examples:

```
First[SymmetricReduction[SchurPolynomial[#, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}, C /@
      Range[3]]] & /@ PadRight[IntegerPartitions[4, 3]]
  {C[1]^4 - 3 C[1]^2 C[2] + C[2]^2 + 2 C[1] C[3],
   C[1]^2 C[2] - C[2]^2 - C[1] C[3], C[2]^2 - C[1] C[3], C[1] C[3]}

With[{pp = IntegerPartitions[5]}, Outer[KostkaNumber, pp, pp, 1]]
   {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5},
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
```